# Custom date formats in angular/devextreme with intl

Tags: angular, date, format, angular-cli, devextreme

How can I globally override the dateformat used by intl and devextreme? Currently, it has correctly loaded the locale de-DE and formats the date like so: **d.m.yyyy**. However, I'd like to display it **dd.mm.yyyy** (2-digit for day and month).

Can the default Intl.DateTimeFormat be somehow overwritten? I'm using angular with angular-cli@6.0.0

Regargs
Gabriel

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, you can set your locale. Please read [Internationalization (i18n)](https://angular.io/guide/i18n) in Angular instructions. There you can find step by step instructions on how to set your locale. By using pipes, you can set date format to your desire.

Comment: He is asking about a library that is using its own formatting and localization logic not about angular in general

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create an overload for each grid. For now it is the only way I found, but I don't like it much, because it is called for each row-column in a grid:

```
import DataGrid from 'devextreme/ui/data_grid';

export class DevextremeUtils {

  public static registerComponentsDefaultOtions(){
    DataGrid.defaultOptions({
      options: {
        customizeColumns: function(ev){
          for(let i = 0; i < ev.length; i++){
            if(ev[i].dataType == 'date' && ev[i].format == 'shortDateShortTime'){
              ev[i].format = {
                year: "numeric",
                  month: "2-digit",
                  day: "2-digit"
              }
            }
          }
        },
      }
    })
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be overwritten but for each widget as far as I know.
You can export a constant containing the intl formatting options and use it with all your widgets.

```
export const format = { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' };
```

That would make all formats regardless of the locale use 2 digits day, 2 digits month, and 4 digits year.
Most of DevExtreme widgets if not all have a configuration that would take a format object.

Reference: https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Common/Object_Structures/format/